# Javascript code in <body> cannot access array in <head>

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner to Javascript and am trying to make sense of why something's not working. I created a simple page with some reference arrays in the `<head>` section which I could then access in the `<body>` So the head section looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var cities = [ "London", "New York" ];
    </script>
  </head>
```

The I want to use this array to drive a dropdown in the body of the HTML so I thought I'd use this:

```
<body>
  <select id="dd_city">
    <script>
      for( i = 0; i < cities.length; i++)
      {
        document.write( "<option value=" + i + ">" + cities[i] + "</option>" )
      }
    </script>
  </select>
  ...
```

I thought that this would be reasonable and it was based on examples I found online. however, I find that it just produces an empty drop down, as if the array is seen as empty. What have I misunderstood or got wrong?

Comment: Short answer: don't put it in the body.

Comment: also I think you need it to be `global_cities`, not `global cities`.

Comment: `script` tags conventionally go in the `<head>` tag of your document, or at the end of the body tag.

Comment: Nothing wrong with putting JS in the body. Indeed, it's advised by some to include JS before the `</body>` tag. The problem is that there is no `global` keyword in JS.

Comment: You should read up on writing valid html.

Comment: I've removed the global keyword but it still does not work.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: What HTML is invalid?

Comment: @Component10, `<select>` tags can not contain `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. There is no keyword `global` in JavaScript.

Change to

```
<script>
  var cities = [ "London", "New York" ];
</script>
```

<sup>Your syntax should give you errors in the console!</sup>

Variables, that are not defined within a function scope are automatically added to the `window` object, which in a browser environment is the global scope. So no need to define anything like a `global` keyword.

Other notes:

- Defining global variables is considered bad practice. It can lead to variable conflicts, when you load multiple scripts.
- `document.write` is generally not a good idea. Better use something like [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) to get your dynamic content in a page.

Comment: OK. I dropped the global but it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I worked out how to get the Javascript console working and discovered that there was an unrelated syntax error that prevented the arrays from being properly defined. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Remove global from in front of cities and use document.GetElementById rather than document.write. Also no need to have script between select tags, as you have a reference to the select id.

Try

```
<head>
    <script>
        var cities = ["London", "New York"];
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="dd_city"/>
        <script>
            for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                var option = "<option value=" + i + ">" + cities[i] + "</option>";
                document.getElementById("dd_city").innerHTML += option;
            }
        </script>
</body>
```

I would also recommend not using a global variable, as this could conflict with other javaScript scripts.

Answer (score 1):

where to begin... first of all it is considered good practice to put your javascript at the bottom of the document right before the closing body tag. see the following link for an explanation as to why that is:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

when you include javascript files at the bottom of the document you will be forced to enclose your code into functions and bind those functions to different events. javascript is very much an event driven language.

this will encourage you to write better code that will be reusable throughout your project. I wont go into a big long lecture on writing good code but i recommend picking up a good book to get you started. like [Javascript The Definitive Guide.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805527)

as to the code you currently have, here's how I would do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
      <select id="dd_city"></select>
      <script>
          var initPage = function() {
              var cities = Array("London", "New York");
              var selectBox = document.getElementById("dd_city");

              for( var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++)
              {
                  var option = document.createElement("option");

                  option.setAttribute("value", i);
                  option.innerHTML = cities[i];
                  selectBox.appendChild(option);
              }
          };

          window.onload = initPage();
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

see it in action at my [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wh1t3w0lf21/V6xAX/1/)